# Adjusting Telerik RadComboBox dropdown width dynamically based on content

Tags: javascript, html, telerik

I'm using Telerik's RadComboBox in my ASP.NET application, and I'm trying to make the dropdown width adjust dynamically based on the content. Currently, I have the following RadComboBox setup in my code:

```
<telerik:RadComboBox ID="wcProductCode" runat="server" CssClass="codingwidthControl" Height="150px" MaxLength="50" DataTextField="DbComboText" OnClientItemsRequested="AfterClientItemRequested" DataValueField="DbComboValue" ItemsPerRequest="10" DropDownAutoWidth="Enabled" ShowMoreResultsBox="true" EnableVirtualScrolling="true" OnClientKeyPressing="OnGlobalClientKeyPressing" OnClientBlur="CheckProductText" OnClientItemsRequesting="wcProductCode_BeforeRequestItems" OnClientSelectedIndexChanged="OnClientSelectedIndexChangedItem">
    <WebServiceSettings Method="DBMethod_ProductCode" Path="~/Services/PurchaseRequisitionForm.asmx" />
</telerik:RadComboBox>
```

I want the dropdown width to adjust itself to the width of the longest sentence or word in the dropdown items. How can I achieve this dynamically? I've tried setting DropDownAutoWidth to "Enabled", but it seems to adjust the width based on the width of the RadComboBox itself, not the content. Is there a way to achieve this without explicitly setting a fixed width?

Any help or guidance on how to achieve this functionality would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

See this link on Telerik's documentation: [Telerik RadComboBox AutoSizeDropdown](https://docs.telerik.com/devtools/aspnet-ajax/controls/combobox/functionality/dropdown-autowidth)

I see you are setting that property on the control itself, however you have applied width and a css class. Both of those can be interfering with the autosizing of the dropdown and should be removed to test.